# How do I enter a value in textbox then have that value execute on another page in php

Tags: php, html

I have a form on my Home.php

```
 <form action="/local-concert-listings/" method="post">
    <input  id="address" size="5" type="text" placeholder="Zipcode" name="search"/>
    <input type="submit" value="go" name="go"  />
</form>
```

I want to submit the form then have it redirect to 'local-concert-listings.php' and have the zipcode value from 'home.php' be the value of the 'local-concert-listings.php' zipcode textbox.

Comment: Use $_get['search']; so when you echo that, it will show your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form action="/local-concert-listings.php" method="post">
    <input  id="address" size="5" type="text" placeholder="Zipcode" name="search"/>
    <input type="submit" value="go"/>
</form>
```

No need name for submit button unless you have more then one submit type.

In your local-concert-listings.php file, you can get your zipcode with

```
$_POST['search'] // this is your zipcode
```

Answer (score 1):

1, Type in information into textbox

2, Click "Go" (your submit button)

3, On this page: `/local-concert-listings/` (which is your forms `action`) retrieve that information using `$_POST` (your forms `method`):

```
if(isset($_POST['search']){
    echo $_POST['search'];
}
```